# Cómo identificar un numero decimal

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa por mi cuenta y me he estancado debido a una duda.

Pasa que quiero que el usuario ingrese dos números. Que se multipliquen y (Aquí está el problema) que el programa revise si el producto de los dos números es múltiplo del número que el usuario también ya ha asignado previamente.

Sé que puedo resolverlo dividiendo el producto entre el múltiplo y que si el número resultante es decimal, no es múltiplo y si no, sí lo es. Estuve pensando en un If Else.

**Quisiera saber cómo hacer que el programa reconozca que la división resulte en un número decimal o por el contrario un numero entero.**

Pues esa condición es lo único que me falta para terminar el programa, me sería de muchísima ayuda si alguien de aquí pudiese ayudarme. Muchas gracias:^)

Aquí debajo está lo que me falta.

```
division == producto / multiplo;

if(//Condicion que me falta)
{
 cout<<"El producto de los números sí es múltiplo de"<<múltiplo;
}
else
{
 cout<<"El producto de los números no es múltiplo de"<<múltiplo;
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a saber cual es el resto de la división? si es asi, puedes usar el operador `%` que devuelve lo que quieres, si devuelve 0 es multiplo
`if((producto % multiplo) == 0){`

Comment: Woow ¡Muchas gracias a quienes respondieron! Supieron resolver mis dudas de una forma muy práctica. Saludos!

Comment: No añadas “gracias” como respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), podrás [votar a favor de preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) que encuentres útiles. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/115118)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quisiera saber cómo hacer que el programa reconozca que la división resulte en un número decimal o por el contrario un numero entero.

Existe una función en la cabecera [`<cmath>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) que te separa un número en coma flotante en sus partes enteras y decimales: [`std::modf` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf):

```
double parte_entera;
double parte_decimal = std::modf(3.14f, &parte_entera);
std::cout << "Pi es " << parte_entera << " + " << parte_decimal << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> Pi es 3 + 0.14
> ```

Para saber si la división de dos números resulta en decimales también puedes hacer una división entera (la cuál descarta decimales) y comprobar si multiplicar los componentes de la división resultan en el número original:

```
bool division_entera(double dividendo, double divisor)
{
    long long r = dividendo / divisor;
    return (r * divisor) == dividendo;
}
```

Usando la función anterior con los números `10` y `2` comprueba que `5` × `2` sea igual a `10`, que será cierto, pero pasando `10` y `3` comprobará que `3` (el resultado de la división entera de `10` entre `3`) × `3` sea igual a `10`, que será falso.

Pero puedes conseguir el mismo efecto con menos código haciendo conversión a entero del número resultante de la división:

```
bool tiene_decimales = (numero == static_cast<long long>(numero));
```

Finalmente, lo más sencillo será simplemente usar el operador de módulo como sugiere [David_helo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/193845/2742), pero como este operador no está disponible para números en coma flotante deberás usar [`std::fmod` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

```
auto resto = std::fmod(producto, multiplo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te dice @GEPD es tan sencillo como usar el operador `%`, el cual divide un número por el otro, y si esta división és exacta (es decir el resiudo es 0) te devuelve un 0, y por lo tanto será igual a 0.

```
if(producto % multiplo == 0)
{
 cout<<"El numero " <<producto<< " sí es múltiplo de "<<múltiplo;
}
else
{
 cout<<"El numero "<<producto<< " no es múltiplo de "<<múltiplo;
}
```

Comment: Ojo, si `num1` y `num2` son números en coma flotante (`float`, `double` o `long double`) no funcionará el operador `%`.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus menos mal que "SOes" cuenta con gente como tu, para darse cuenta de las múltiples excepciones que la demás gente no somos capaces de imaginarnos. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias por apreciarlo David :P pero es más experiencia que imaginación: "[*sabe más el diablo por viejo, que por diablo*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=59028&Lng=0)".

Answer (score 0):

Para comprobar si una el resultado de una división es un número entero o un número con decimales tienes que observar el resto de la división. Para calcular el resto se usa el operador %.

```
resto = num1 % num2;

if (resto == 0) {
    // al dividir la variable num1 entre num2 da como resultado un número entero
} else if (resto != 0) {
    // al dividir la variable num1 entre num2 da como resultado un número decimal
}
```

Comment: Ojo, si `num1` y `num2` son números en coma flotante (`float`, `double` o `long double`) no funcionará el operador `%`.